# Social Network API design for Like, Comment, and other Interactions?

Tags: asp.net, social-networking, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a website where I showcase people's artwork, recipes, and journals (and this list is likely to grow). I want people to be able to comment, like, flag, etc. all of them.

I'm not looking for a database schema. I am using ASP.net Web API but the platform should be irrelevant. I am passing an Authorization Bearer header to identify the user who wants to like, comment on, flag, etc. another user's work.

I currently have two "schemes" but I'm not sure what the advantages/disadvantages of each one is, so I can't make a good decision.

---

The first looks like this:

```
POST api/<entity>/{id}/<action>
```

For example, api/journal/21793/like, or api/recipe/1005/comment. Of course, each action would have the appropriate body that includes info to store to the back end.

Implementing it this way, though, would require us to write entityCount x interactionTypeCount functions (actions), which is very tedious, though the API call is friendly.

---

The second API scheme looks like this:

```
POST api/<action>
```

For example, api/like, api/comment - and yes, there would be no way to depict which object type and which record of the object type in the URL. So, if we were to comment on the recipe mentioned, we would call:

```
POST api/comment

{"id":"1005", "objectType":"recipe", "comment":"This was excellent!"}
```

This way, we call only 1 API to comment on anything in our system. So, each of the POST api/ functions would require the id and objectType properties in the body, plus whatever other required data as appropriate for the action. (I'm using JSON as an example).

I see that developers would have to know beforehand what our accepted objectType values are in order to post interactions to the right record. I'm not sure if this is option is a good idea.

---

This question might get flagged for being off-topic or open to debate, but I'm hoping someone can tell me more pros and cons of each approach indicated above so I can make a better decision. Better yet, offer a solution that is either totally different or combines aspects of the two approaches above.